# Can I have both GA4 and Universal Analytics dataLayer on my e-commerce?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer, enhanced-ecommerce

I am doing the migration from UA to GA4 on my site, but I need that both properties keep working for some time. My problem is setting the dataLayer, I do not know how to have both of the e-commerce objects without conflict. I know that I can map the variables to GA4 format by GTM, but since the Google documentation recommends setting up GA4 datalayer, and that UA will die soon, I would like to have both dataLayers in my site.

I was thinking of something generic like:

```
dataLayer.push( {ecommerce: null} )
dataLayer.push( {ecommerce: UA template} )
dataLayer.push( {ecommerce: GA4 template} )
```

So I will have both objects in my dataLayer. Does that work without conflicts?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Universal Analytics dataLayer, for example with Google Tag Manager, send ecommerce events as well as to Universal Analytics property also to GA4 property managing the various parameters as expected by this last data collection model: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/ecommerce?client_type=gtm

No conflict can exist because the data is sent to two different systems.